# What is the difference between #const and const?

Tags: vba

[This class, which runs just fine](https://github.com/VBA-tools/VBA-Dictionary/commit/475b5e86c8ede5bfa835f8322c58265379bde106) contains lines like `#Const UseScriptingDictionaryIfAvailable = True`. I normally use `Const UseScriptingDictionaryIfAvailable As Boolean = True`.

I've noticed you can't explicitly declare the type with #const. Whereas `As Boolean` is optional in the later, its forbidden in the former. Is that the only difference? Is there an internal difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That # is for conditional compilation. If you want to conditionally compile a certain piece of code, you can use #. For example:

```
#Const MyEnv = "Testing"

Sub TestMacro()

 #If MyEnv = "Testing" Then
   ' do something here
   Debug.Print "Logging for testing"
   Dim X as String
   X = "..."
 #Else
   Dim Y as Int
   Y = 100
 #End If

End Sub
```

https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/06/26/vba-trick-of-the-week-conditional-compiling/ link provides a good description of conditional compilation.

http://www.utteraccess.com/wiki/index.php/Conditional_Compilation also provides some good inputs.

Answer (score 0):

`Const` is your everyday "normal" constant declaration.

`#Const` is different, it lets you define constants specifically for use with compiler directives like `#If`.

A "normal" constant wouldn't be available for the compiler to use for conditional compilation:

```
Const DEBUG As Boolean = True
```

However this would:

```
#Const DEBUG = True
```